# onChangeMonthYear option in YII framework

Tags: yii, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can anyone tell me why it is not working for me?

Actual question: When browsing dates in the date picker, a default day has to be selected if no selection is done.

I did it manually in the Jquery Datepicker but in YII using Zii Widget i am not 
getting.

```
$this->datePickerOptions = array(
  'showAnim' => 'fold',
  'dateFormat'=>'dd M yy',
  'changeMonth' => 'true',`enter code here`
  'changeYear'=>'true',
  'constrainInput' => 'false',
  'firstDay' => 1,

  'onChangeMonthYear' => 'js:function (year, MM, inst) {
     var selectedDate = new Date();
     _currentDay=this.value.toString().substr(0,2);
     selectedDate = Date.parse(MM + "" + _currentDay + " " + year );
     this.value=selectedDate.toString("dd MMM yyyy");
   }'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'onChangeMonthYear'=>'js:function(y, m, i){                                
                      var d = i.selectedDay;
                      $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(y, m - 1, d));
                      }'
```

like this i fixed the problem, now when i am changing the month and year in text field also changing the dates.
thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a default. If nothing has changed during selection time, the default will remain untouched.

```
'defaultDate'=>'0000-00-00',
```